# MapReduce - Read file from provided path

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I am using below code to read a file path provided in my Mapper. The code was mentioned in one of the similar question.

```
    import java.io.BufferedReader;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.InputStreamReader;
    import java.util.*;

    import org.apache.hadoop.conf.*;
    import org.apache.hadoop.fs.*;
    import org.apache.hadoop.io.*;
    import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.*;
    import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.*;
    import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.*;
    import org.apache.hadoop.util.*;
    import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapReduceBase;

     import java.util.StringTokenizer;

     public class StubDriver {

// Main Method 

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    Configuration conf = new Configuration(); // Configuration Object       
    Job job = new Job(conf, "My Program");  
    FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(conf);       
    job.setJarByClass(StubDriver.class);
    job.setMapperClass(Map1.class);
    // job.setPartitionClass(Part1);
    // job.setReducerClass(Reducer1);
    // job.setNumReduceTasks(3);

    job.setInputFormatClass(TextInputFormat.class);
    job.setOutputFormatClass(TextOutputFormat.class);

    TextInputFormat.addInputPath(job,new Path(args[0]));;
    TextOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));

    job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);
    job.setMapOutputKeyClass(IntWritable.class);
    job.setMapOutputValueClass(Text.class);

    job.waitForCompletion(true);        
}

// Mapper

public static class Map1 extends Mapper<LongWritable,Text,IntWritable,Text>  {

    public void setup(Context context) throws IOException {

        Path pt = new Path("hdfs://quickstart.cloudera:8020/dhawalhdfs/input/*");
        FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(new Configuration());
        BufferedReader br= new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fs.open(pt)));
        String line;
        line = br.readLine();
        while (line != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
            line = br.readLine();

        }               

    }


    public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

        StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(value.toString());

        String a = tokenizer.nextToken();
        String b = tokenizer.nextToken();
        String c = tokenizer.nextToken();
        String d = tokenizer.nextToken();
        String e = tokenizer.nextToken();

        context.write(new IntWritable(Integer.parseInt(c)),new Text(a + "\t" + b + "\t" + d + "\t" + e));

        }       
}                                           
}
```

Code compilation is successful. I am facing error while submitting the job.. As i am providing input path in my program, i am trying to submit only output path as below -

```
hadoop jar /home/cloudera/dhawal/MR/Par.jar StubDriver /dhawalhdfs/dhawal000
```

and i am getting error as

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
at StubDriver.main(StubDriver.java:40)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:221)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136)
```

Comment: Whether your issue is solved?

Answer (score 0):

Its a simple mistake... :-)

```
new Path(
```

> args[1]

`));` is the source of error. where you are trying to pass one argument of array and you are trying to read second element

You are accessing in your stub driver like below

```
TextInputFormat.addInputPath(job,new Path(args[0]));;
TextOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));
```

but for driver you are passing only one argument like below

```
hadoop jar /home/cloudera/dhawal/MR/Par.jar StubDriver /dhawalhdfs/dhawal000
```

Ideally you should be passing argument separated by a space

```
hadoop jar /home/cloudera/dhawal/MR/Par.jar StubDriver /dhawalhdfs   /dhawal000
```

Comment: Yes,in this case /dhawalhdfs becomes my input path which is not valid. I am trying to provide input path in my Mapper. Is there any change i need to make in my code so that input path is read from mapper and output path is taken from the command line?

Comment: no change in code.. you need to add space between your input path and output path. That's all

Comment: Then how will it consider the input path which i have provided into mapper as - Path pt = new Path("hdfs://quickstart.cloudera:8020/dhawalhdfs/input/*");

Comment: since it is relative path it will consider. just like if you wan to query hdfs then you will say hadoo fs -ls /dhawalhdfs/input/* rather than giving complete path right... in the same way it will consider relative path. Hope you understood

Comment: any queries from you ?

Comment: Yes..my original question is still not answered. Since i am giving input path in my mapper, which command should i use to run this program?

Comment: you are using TextInputFormat and addInputpath method you should pass valid path based on which input splits were prepared using record reader.  you avoid hard coding of the path and pass the path through addInputPath method. [pls see examples](http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.TextInputFormat). hard coding is not good practice

Comment: however is original exception i.e array out of bound exception is because you are passing  one arguement i.e args[0] when you are executing hadoop jar ... .command